# Auto Loading HTML in a Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to use this code in JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/syE7s/  to load some content into a div.

It's exactly what I need but I want link A to auto load when the page loads. My knowledge of Javascript is fairly minimal so if someone could get it working in jsfiddle I would be very greatful.

I've tried googling everything but I just can't seem to make it work.

It is essential I use the HTML as the links I use parse tokens that use {} to identify them as tokens but it obviously gets confused with Javascript when they are sat together.

```
enter code here
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working JS Fiddle, I added a function to load the first link :

```
function launch() {
    var link = $('#A').attr("href");
    $('#target').load(link);
}

launch();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhmLjme6/

Comment: He added an `ID` to the `<a>` element so he could select it. Then created a function to get the `href` of that element and use it to `.load()` it to the `#target` element. Then he called the function. so it launches after the document has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can add just one line to your javascript.

It will look like this (**line 3**):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#target').load($('.trigger').attr("href"));

  $('.trigger').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");

      $('#target').load(link);

  });
});
```

Comment: This will select the first `element` with the **trigger** class.

Comment: I know. In this specific case it will work. But I think it's clear for him to understand what he has to do to load on page load...

Comment: Yes, it will work right now if he doesn't decide to add another link. He stated *"My knowledge of Javascript is fairly minimal"* so I figured I would explain it so he understands a little better. :)

Comment: Ye I think you did well and your explanation is more accurate. I even upvoted :)